# How to have multiple hostnames in single ansible template?

Tags: python, ansible, drbd

I want to generate a file which is the same on two hosts and contains both host names, e.g.:

```
resource r0 {
  on host01 {
    device    /dev/drbd0;
  }
  on host02 {
    device    /dev/drbd0;
  }
}
```

I tried to achieve this with a template such as the following:

```
resource r0 {
  on {{ hostvars[groups['hosts'][0]]['ansible_nodename'] }} {
    device    /dev/drbd0;
  }
  on {{ hostvars[groups['hosts'][1]]['ansible_nodename'] }} {
    device    /dev/drbd0;
  }
}
```

This works for the first variable, but the list doesn't have a second element,
so the second variable is unknown.

How do I get a list of the hosts so that I can select each host individually from the list?

Edit: The relevant bit of the inventory is

```
[hosts]
host01
host02
```

Edit:

My answer below works if I just need the host name.  However, I also need
the IP address of a certain interface.

How do I access something like the information in `hostvars` but for a host
other than the current one?

Comment: Can you also add your inventory file (or a relevant snippet of it)?

Answer (score 0):

The following does what I want:

```
resource r0 {
  on {{ groups['hosts'][0] }} {
    device    /dev/drbd0;
  }
  on {{ groups['hosts'][1] }} {
    device    /dev/drbd0;
  }
}
```

Edit:

To access variables of hosts other than the current one, such as IP addresses, the playbook must include the other hosts in a `hosts` instruction.  I was testing with a playbook which only ran for a single host and so was unable to access information about the other host.  You can still run a test like this, but you need a dummy action over the other hosts, as described here: https://serverfault.com/a/639269/144800, in order to collect the facts for the other hosts.